# Typical Android USB and MicroUSB throughput/bandwidth

Tags: android, usb

I'm looking into utilizing the MicroUSB connection of my Android phone for an app I am developing.

At the moment I have tried USB tethering and connecting to my app over TCP. However this results in very low bandwidth, even comparable to my Wifi connection, at about 10 mbit/s estimated. I figure the connection is throttled by Android possibly.

Before I set up a custom ADK (Accessory Development Kit) connection or communicate instead over an ADB connection, what can I expect for those connections in terms of speed compared to USB tethering?

I am looking to have an easy and well-supported connection for the phone side, so as I see it now, USB tethering would be most supported.

**Edit**

I am on Android 4.4 KitKat and my current host is Ubuntu. I've heard stories that Windows provides faster speeds with Android USB tethering, is that true?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? It would be really helpful to me, if you could share your findings/experience.

Comment: Depends on USB port, but I don´t think the speed is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> about 10 mbit/s estimated

Sounds like 12 MBit/s USB 1.1 "Full Speed" and not USB 2.0 High speed.

You can actually check with `lsusb -t` whether a device runs at high speed:

```
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/6p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=pl2303, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
```

Comment: I've looked and it's not USB1.1, it says 480M. Thanks for the tip though.